# Comparing values after ChangeType not working

Tags: c#, if-statement, integer, comparison, changetype

I have the problem, that comparing values after changing the type (in this case to int) does not work:

[image]

In my point of view (see the debugger), `_pkValue` and `_defaultValue` are both `integers` with the same value.

The problem is, that the if-statement should not be entered, because both values are `0`.

I'm sure it is a very simple thing, but i can't figure it out.

**EDIT: Code**

```
object pkVal = pks.First().Value.GetValue(this, null);

if (pkVal != null)
{
    var defaultValue = TypeHelper.GetDefaultValue(pkVal.GetType());

    var _pkValue = Convert.ChangeType(pkVal, pkVal.GetType());
    var _defaultValue = Convert.ChangeType(defaultValue, pkVal.GetType());

    if (_pkValue != _defaultValue)
    {
        canset = false;
    }
}
```

**SOLUTION**

```
object pkVal = pks.First().Value.GetValue(this, null);

if (pkVal != null)
{
    var defaultValue = Simplic.TypeHelper.GetDefaultValue(pks.First().Value.PropertyType);

    if (!pkVal.Equals(defaultValue))
    {
        canset = false;
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Would be better to see your work as a text..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `_pkValue` and `_defaultValue` aren't *pure* integers, they're [boxed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/yz2be5wk.aspx).

The static type of the variables is `object`, which means that your `!=` operator is checking for reference equality rather than comparing the boxed integer values.

You can use the polymorphic [`Equals`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx) method to check for value equality:

```
if (!_pkValue.Equals(_defaultValue))
{
    canset = false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, changed my question with the final solution, because some code lines are not needed any more.